# A closed ideal in a commutative Banach algebra $C(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Suppose that $A$ is a natural Banach function algebra on $K$, a compact Hausdorff space. So $A$ is realised as an algebra of continuous functions on $K$, is a Banach algebra for some norm (necessarily dominating the supremum norm) and each character on $A$ is given by evaluation at a point of $K$.

If $F\subseteq K$ is closed, then how can we prove that
$I(F)=\{f\in A\mid f(k)=0,\, k\in F\}$ is also closed?

Comment: Consider the case $F = \{x\}$ first.

Comment: then it becomes I(x)= {f∈A | f(x)=0} which is kernel of a linear functional Φx(f)=f(x), so it is closed.
but  for general F, how can we prove it?

Comment: $$I(F) = \bigcap_{x\in F} I(x)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer To me it looks as if for any $f$ not in $I(x)$ you can just find an epsilon ball in the $\sup$ norm to show the complement of $I(x)$ is open. But then all the additional assumptions are not needed (like "natural" and that $K$ is Hausdorff and the thing about the characters).

Comment: @MattN. Yes, that too. We need that the topology is not coarser than the $\sup$-norm topology, but that is all. The other assumptions guarantee that every character is an evaluation, but for the closedness, that is irrelevant, only that evaluations are continuous is needed.

Comment: @DanielFischer I went ahead and made your comments into an answer. Hope it's ok.

Comment: @MattN. Sure is.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd make the comments by Daniel Fischer into an answer. Here goes:

All that remains to be done now is to show that $I(x)$ is closed. We show $I^c (x)$ is open. To this end, let $f \in I^c(x)$. Then $f(x) \neq 0$. Since the norm on $A$ dominates $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, we know that there exists $C \in \mathbb R$ such that $\|f\|_\infty \le C  \|f\|$ for all $f\in A$. Hence if we choose $\delta = {|f(x)| \over 2C}$ and consider $g \in B_{\|\cdot\|}(f,\delta)$ then 
$$ |g(x)-f(x)| \le \|g - f \|_\infty  \le C\|g-f\| < {|f(x)| \over 2}$$
and hence $|g(x)| \ge {|f(x)| \over 2} > 0$ which shows that $g \in I^c (x)$ and hence $B_{\|\cdot\|}(f,\delta) \subseteq I^c (x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $g\in \overline{I(F)}$ so there is $f_{n}\in I(F)$ such that $f_{n}\to g$ on $K$. Sinc $F\subseteq K$  is compact, so for each $k\in F$ we have $f_{n}(k)\to g(k)$, but $f_{n}(k)=0$, therefore $g(k)=0$. Thus $g\in I(F)$. so $\overline{I(F)} \subseteq I(F)$.